# Xcode debug view hierarchy shows blank white screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Upon hitting the "Debug View Hierarchy" button in the debug area toolbar while in any scene of my app, I am received with a screen that contains the buttons for controlling the 3D hierarchy (show clipped content, show constraints, etc.) but does not render any UI elements; it is left as a blank white space. This error displays in the console as soon as the button is hit:

```
2015-07-05 23:10:01.771 app-name[2204:31187] -[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7878ef50
2015-07-05 23:10:01.781 app-name[2204:31187] -[NSCoder(CACoderAdditions) CA_encodeObject:forKey:conditional:]: ignoring exception -[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7878ef50
```

I can't seem to find the cause of this error. The actual app renders fine with no warnings. Cleaning the project and restarting Xcode has no effect. I am using Xcode 6.3.1 and running iOS 8.3 on both the iPhone 5 and 5s simulator.

Comment: I do have one suggestion: instead of "hitting the Debug View Hierarchy button", thus pausing your app at some random point, put a breakpoint in your code somewhere so that your code is already paused, and _now_ debug the view hierarchy.

Comment: @matt Unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: was having same issue on simulator with 8.1, changing to the simulator of 9.3 seems to be working , so not sure if it solves for you but seems like switching the simulator works sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Xcode's view debugger is not mature yet.
Your bug frequently happens to me when using complex view hierarchies.
A good workaround is to use [Spark Inspector](http://sparkinspector.com/) (it has a free full-feature trial) for now, until Apple fixes the issue.